Formbuilder conditional logic action?
CiviCRM community,
I'm just wondering if I can use FormBuilder to create an activity based on a field value of another activity.
Context:
I have a form that volunteers use to report their calls to seniors, so they complete the Activity 1 form to create a "Volunteer report" activity. But inside the Activity 1 form, I have a field used when the report has any urgency or issue necessary to alert a case coordinator. This field is a simple yes or no question.
So, if the volunteer marks yes to that field, the form could create another activity (Activity 2) "Volunteer report alert" with high priority and in a "scheduled" state, filed in the same case.
Do you think this is possible??, I successfully did this with Caldera Forms in the past, but now I don't know how to accomplish this, I'm trying to avoid third-party (WordPress) plugins.

Here is my workaround if someone faces a similar scenario
I've created Activity 2 to add an alert. But in Formbuilder I've added the subject, case n°, priority, and activity status fields as hidden fields. So, if the user marks in the previous question "yes", the form shows just case n° and "alert reasons".
As a result, if the user marks "yes" and sends the form. Creates the activity "alert" with subject and priority "urgent" and fills in the case. If no, the activity "alert" is also created outside the case and without subject and standard priority and status. So as the next step, I made a CiviRule that adds a tag to every "alert" activity with normal priority with a "delete" tag.
Now I'm dealing with automating a "clean" job that deletes every activity with a "delete" tag daily. If someone has any idea I will be grateful.
I share my workaround if should be useful for anyone in a similar scenario.

I don't think you can do that purely with FormBuilder but CiviRules should let you create the second activity.

I tried to do this with CiviRules but I can't see the option to create a case activity (or file the activity within the case). May I'm forgetting something?
